# How does the browser treat multiple $(document).keypress methods?

Tags: javascript, jquery, web

I'm building an application that constantly listening to key presses. I use the $(document).keypress method, passing it

```
function(e) {

if (e.keyCode == 13) { if (currentStep === 1) {...} }

if (e.keyCode == 13) { if (currentStep === 2) {...} }

...

}
```

With many ifs inside. For reason of convenience, I would strongly prefer to "split" the keypress code to different locations in my code. So instead of this:

```
$(document).keypress(function(e) {

if (e.keyCode == 13) { if (currentStep === 1) {...} }

if (e.keyCode == 13) { if (currentStep === 2) {...} }

...

}
```

I would write it like this:

```
$(document).keypress(function(e) {

if (e.keyCode == 13) { if (currentStep === 1) {...} }

}

$(document).keypress(function(e) {

if (e.keyCode == 13) { if (currentStep === 2) {...} }

}
```

Does it make any difference?

Comment: The fact that you have two event bindings on the same event, checking for the same key code, imho, is a code smell.  Especially if they are declared in relatively the same place in your scripts.

Comment: It seems you have different states that you move through based on what was pressed and what was pressed before it, so here is a suggestion: designing this as a state machine in order to properly investigate the valid and invalid states then produce the correct logic for handling them.